# Selenium-jupiter - passing timeout in browsers.json

Tags: selenium, selenium-jupiter

I am trying to write selenium tests using Selenium-Jupiter. My team has decided to go with `@TestTemplate` approach and to use `browsers.json`.

One thing we feel we need to do is alter the default timeouts. I have read on [the selenium documentation that you can use the shared capability](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#timeouts) "timeouts" to do so. We also know that you can specify capabilities in `browsers.json`.

I have ran out of ideas, I have tried the following two ways and neither sets timeouts correctly:

```
{
  "browsers": [
    [
      {
        "type": "edge",
        "version": "latest",
        "capabilities": {
           "timeouts": {"implicit": 10000, "pageLoad": 10000, "script": 30000}
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "browsers": [
    [
      {
        "type": "edge",
        "version": "latest",
        "capabilities": {
           "timeouts": "{\"implicit\": 10000, \"pageLoad\": 10000, \"script\": 30000}"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The former gets ignored and has no effect. The latter causes a failure when creating a WebDriver instance. I am starting to think this is not supported. :-(

**Edit 1**

I am using Java. Here is part of our `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Which language binding art are you using? Update the question with your code block about how you implement the browser capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Selenium-Jupiter does not support that feature, sorry. The possible capabilities to be specified in the JSON scenario are simple key-value strings (see [example](https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter/blob/master/src/test/resources/browsers-caps.json)).